# How to turn off slide animation on Mahapps.Metro Window on load?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mahapps.metro

Does any know how turn off the animation when the `Mahaaps.metro` WPF window loads? Everything appears to load from the right to left. How can I turn this off? I do not see any mentioned of this in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Set WindowTransitionsEnabled="False" on the Window itself.

Comment: I don't seem to have this property available, any idea why? The window is a Controls:MetroWindow and it inherits from MetroWindow appropriately. Very strange.

Comment: @goldenratio maybe you need to update to latest version of Mahapps.Metro to see this property

Answer (score 3):

By default it should work with latest Mapapp build. 
However, it was broken for when Form includes WebBrowser controls.
Setting WindowTransitionsEnabled="False" as mentioned by "chaiwalla" resolves the problem